# can't import existing sql file to an empty database: db_name.table_name doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, import, opencart

I'm trying to import existing database file into an empty SQL database with the following command:

`mysql -u username -p'password' db_name < dbfile.sql`

but I get following Error:

*ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'db_name.oc_address' doesn't exist*

I know that oc_address is a table name inside the SQL file, but I don't know what to do to import it correctly, I searched the web and also stack-overflow, found nothing on this error.

Comment: check the sql file if there is a CREATE TABLE, i doubt it

Comment: no, there isn't CREATE TABLE inside it

Comment: Then rerun the Export, setting the correct requirements, or go in manually and make the tables as well as the database and then run the Import

Comment: there is a lot of tables and several column per table inside the database, should I add CREATE TABLE for all of them? I can't export another way, it's exported using opencart.

Comment: You need to add create table statements if the tables do not exist in the target database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download the actual opencart zip file

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/download/download&download_id=62

- Unzip it
- open folder

> \upload\install

and

- run opencart.sql

if you have installed extensions that have need their own sql, you have to run their sql as well

- After that run you backup file

Answer (score 2):

To export an entire database and then load it into another server, your best bet is to use the [mysqldump command line utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).  Its export files contain the data definition language (tables, views, all that) for the database as well as the data.

You can also get it to export just the definitions.

```
mysqldump --no-data -u username -p'password' db_name > opencartddl.sql
```

Then you can import that file first, then your data file.

Or, you may be able to stand up a new, empty, Opencart instance and use its UI to import your data.

It's probably wise to avoid  trying to write replacement DDL yourself if you can get a tool like mysqldump to do it.